# Dynamically mapping data contract in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-binding

I am facing some issue while passing the data contract values to WCF service without adding a service reference.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();

EndpointAddress adress = new EndpointAddress
("http://localhost:8734/BankVerification.svc");

ChannelFactory<IBankVerification> factory = new ChannelFactory<IBankVerification>(binding, adress);

IBankVerification channel = factory.CreateChannel();

var response = await channel.CallBankVerificationSoapService(message);
```

Here

1. `CallBankVerificationSoapService` is the method in my service
2. `IBankVerification` is the service contract name.

Every thing is fine if I don't pass any parameter to my service. I am able to call the service.

**BUT** when I invoke `channel.CallBankVerificationSoapService(message);`

And I have properties value coming in "message" object but it is not reaching to my invoked WCF service. The receiving object value becomes Null there.
I have added [DataContract], [DataMember] Attribute all the required places.

Am I missing something...?

Comment: Is the instance of the message object in your client in the same namespace as the message object in the service?  Can you post the code of the message object?

Comment: no, See I have a service library project , from there I m invoking.
but I have made some intermediate service contract that point original WCF service.

Comment: That is most likely the issue.  If you have `MyService.SomeObject` defined in your service, and then you have `MyClient.SomeObject` defined in the client, even if the code is exactly the same, they will be treated as different objects because of the namespace difference.  And if you've changed the code between the client and the service, then it definitely will not work.

Comment: So In case suppose the flow is like this WebAPI --> Class libray project1 --> ClassLib project 2 --> call some SOAP service.

and if we to call the service from ClassLib project 2 by the method I mentioned, how we can keep the Object in the same name space.

Comment: Put the object(s) in a separate assembly, and share that assembly with the projects that need it.

Comment: That's ok.. But I was wondering If I will a add the assembly as reference than that basically means I can add service reference and make SOAP call.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I'm saying.  Take the `message` object (and any other objects that are passed to/returned from the service) and put them *all* in one assembly (a class library).  Then reference that assembly in every project (client, service, intermediaries,etc) that need the `message` object.   So in your example in the comment, you could potentially add this shared assembly to WebAPI, Class Library Project 1, Class Library Project 2 and your SOAP service.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try tomaro my day and let u know in either case..

Comment: @Tim I have done it in the way:
I have generated the proxy file by svcutill and replace just with the contracts of my calling project.